# Visual Studio Code / VS Code: Turn off Cursor line/Current line Highlight option

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not sure how I made this feature but I can't stop highlighting the cursor line. As you can see, I have a green underline at the position of the cursor line.

[image]

This feature is good if you do not use .ipynb/jupyter file but if you do you can see this:

[image]

I have looked all settings and also deleted .json setting file parameters to be sure not there but did not work.
Does anyone knows the exact parameter name that I can turn off this feature?

Comment: I found the issue. Unfortunately it was an extension called: "Highlight Line" . We can close the question

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, but later I found that is the column select mode. You need to remove it from the setting.json

```
"editor.columnSelection": true
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.